# iMovie Auto update

Tags: software-update, imovie, auto-update

I bought my Apple IPad in 2017. How can I update the iMovie software in my iPad so that I get additional features like reducing background noise, equaliser etc.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Have you since updated the iOS (by running Software Update under Settings app)? Did you check if the pre-installed App Store app is displaying any available update for the installed iMovie app?

Comment: Yes. IOS a is regularly updated whenever I get a notification.

Comment: Open this link on your iPad and see if shows an update available: https://apps.apple.com/app/imovie/id377298193#?platform=ipad

Comment: All app updates (iMovie included) show up in the App Store as updates via the little red dot with a number in it on the App Store icon. If you have iMovie on your iPad and there are no updates in the App store then you have the latest version of iMovie.

Comment: Thank you very much @Steve Chambers. There are no updates in the App Store. So may be I’m having the latest version. But I see several videos in YouTube with Reduce Background Noise and Equaliser buttons, which are not there in my ipad